# React, check state if key pair exists depending on parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So I'm trying to figure out how to use kind of an all-encompassing function to reduce bloat in my application. I've got a bunch of dialog windows that are handled via state, similar to this:

```
toggleSettingsDialogue = () => {
    this.setState({settingsOpen: !this.state.settingsOpen});
}
```

I'm trying to reduce this function, which is repeated for each additional dialog, into one. My thought is to pass in two parameters - one for the dialog that's meant to be opened, and another that defines the state of that dialog - either true or false.

The issue is, I'm stuck on figuring out how to check if the first parameter passed (i.e. the name of the dialog window in state) exists or not.

Let's say we've got a state with...

```
state = {
     diagSettingsOpen: false,
     diagAddItemOpen: false
}
```

How would I check to see if any string passed as a parameter inside the function is actually there or not, and subsequently use that key to set state if it matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 toggleSettingsDialogue = key => {
   if(key in this.state)
     this.setState(({[key]: val}) => ({[key]: !val}));
}
```

Comment: @IkeDoud glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can check the same -

```js
let state = {
     diagSettingsOpen: false,
     diagAddItemOpen: false
}

function setState(stateName, value) {
    if (state.hasOwnProperty(stateName)) {
        state[stateName] = value;
    } else {
        console.log("invalid state");
    }
}

setState("diagSettingsOpen" ,true);
console.log(state);
setState("diagSettingsClose" ,true);
```